# IE "friendly" HTTP 404 error

Tags: internet-explorer, http-status-code-404

I know there are some questions similar to this, but none I saw were enough to help...

I have a regular php page which is working absolutely fine in FF and Chrome, but in IE, about 20% of the time, it comes up with a (not-so-)'friendly' HTTP 404 error. When friendly errors are turned off, it works fine too. But my page visitors won't have them turned off...
I thought it might be because of a mod_rewrite on the page, but even with that turned off and cache deleted the actual page itself is producing the error. It's so strange, because 80% of the time the page loads perfectly fine, but a refresh or a link back to the same page will result in a 404, and then another few refreshes and it's back.
I don't have access to server logs, because I'm using a 3rd party server and they said there's no logs I can get access to.

Could anyone suggest please what might be causing this problem? Is there a way to see client-side exactly where the 404 came from? Has anyone seen such a thing before - that a page loads sometimes and other times not?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you set `Expires` header ?

Comment: There are no access logs recording 404 errors? I don't know the specifics of the situation, but that sounds incredibly unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I don't understand it at all because it happened even when mod_rewrite was off...
But basically it seems it was to do with wordpress... In a nutshell, every page is being loaded into one template php page which loads the right wordpress page into that php page based on the url, and there was no wordpress page with the 'slug' for a particular (fake) page, but once I created one it works fine. I guess people who really understand mod_rewrite and how wordpress works will understand this better than me, but that's how it got fixed in case anyone else ever has the same problem...

And yes, no server logs is ridiculous!

Thanks!